# Laravel API: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-blade, laravel-api

I am working on API. I want to create login API. I have created `UsersController` in API folder it in controllers. When I run in postman I shows an error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\API\UsersController] does not exist. in file F:\University_Data\xamp\htdocs\stylooworld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 835

I don't now why its duplicated the routing path Target class **[App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\API\UsersController]**

**api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\API')->group(function () {

    Route::post('login', 'UsersController@loginUser');
});
```

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function loginUser(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($data);
            die;
            if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']])) {

                // check email is activated or not (Only Work Online Server)
                /*   $userStatus = User::where('email', $data['email'])->first();
                if ($userStatus->status == 0) {
                    Auth::logout();
                    $message = "Your account is not activated yet! Please confirm your email to activate!";
                    Session::flash('error_message', $message);
                    return redirect()->back();
                }*/

                //update user cart with user id
                if (!empty(Session::get('session_id'))) {
                    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
                    Cart::where('session_id', $session_id)->update(['user_id' => $user_id]);
                }

                return redirect('/');
            } else {
                $message = "Invalid Username or Password";
                Session::flash('error_message', $message);
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Update the routes.
For details please check (ref link) https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates

Use like this

**api.php**

If not working

```
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\API')->group(function () {
Route::post('login', 'UsersController@loginUser');
});
```

Then Use like this

```
use App\Http\Controllers\API\UsersController;
Route::post('login', [UsersController::class, 'loginUser']);
```

Answer (score 0):

import method  Request

class Request extends SymfonyRequest implements Arrayable, ArrayAccess

on click (import method) always ready.
are you ok.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed

```
Route::get('/products','ApiController@getAllProducts');
```

to

```
Route::get('products', [ApiController::class, 'getAllProducts']);
```

…and it works.